# Custom file name while downloading

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there a way to download excel with custom file name. Below downloads with default excel name. Can we make it custom. Like "df.xlsx"

```
DT::datatable(df,
                    escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE,selection = 'single',
                    extensions = c('Buttons'),
                    options = list(
                      scrollX = TRUE,
                      paging = TRUE,
                      buttons = c('excel'),
                      columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(2))),                                     
                      pageLength = 400, sScrollY = '40vh',
                      autoWidth = FALSE,
                      buttons = list('copy', 'print',
                                     list(
                                       extend = 'collection',
                                       buttons = c('csv', 'excel'),
                                       text = 'Download'
                                     ))
                    )
      )
```

Comment: Checkout the following post on github --> https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/409 - It exactly covers your topic!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
buttons = list(list(extend = "excel", text = "Export to XLSX", filename = "yourCustomFileName"))
```